# Print alternatively one element from the last and one from the first (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numbers, logic

Print alternatively one element from the last and one from the first  (JavaScript)

*input*
1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 8

*output:*
8, 1, 2, 3, 3, 6

Comment: This looks more like a requirement, what is your question?

Comment: required logic for this problem with source code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: For a given set of numbers print alternatively on element from the first and one element from the last.(using arrays)    input : 1 2 3 4 5 6     output:   1 6 2 5 3 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below approach

```js
var array = [];
var size = prompt('Enter Array Size'); //Maximum Array size

for(var i=0; i<size; i++) {
    
    //Taking Input from user
    array[i] = prompt('Enter Element ' + (i+1));
}

//Print the array in the console.
console.log("Array Input: "+array.join(','));

let output = [];
    let l = array.length - 1;
    for (let i = 0; i <= l; i++, l--) {
        if (i>=array.length/2) {
            console.log(array[i]);
            break;
        }
        output.push(array[l]);
        output.push(array[i]);
    }

console.log("Resultant Array: "+output.join(','));
```

Comment: yes, perfect solution. but, for this problem how can i take input from user

Answer (score 0):

Anyways you can try the below logic.

```js
const input = [1, 3, 6, 3, 2, 8];
let output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length / 2; i++) {
  output.push(input[i]);
  output.push(input[input.length - (i + 1)]);
}
```